# Android incoming call recording

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I am trying to record the incoming voice call of the user.

My code is :

```
public class TService extends Service {
    MediaRecorder recorder;
    File audiofile;
    String name, phonenumber;
    String audio_format;
    public String Audio_Type;
    int audioSource;
    Context context;
    private Handler handler;
    Timer timer;
    Boolean offHook = false, ringing = false;
    Toast toast;
    Boolean isOffHook = false;
    private boolean recordstarted = false;

    private static final String ACTION_IN = "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE";
    private static final String ACTION_OUT = "android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL";
    private CallBr br_call;


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }



    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d("service", "destroy");

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // final String terminate =(String)
        // intent.getExtras().get("terminate");//
        // intent.getStringExtra("terminate");
        // Log.d("TAG", "service started");
        //
        // TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)
        // getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); // TelephonyManager
        // // object
        // CustomPhoneStateListener customPhoneListener = new
        // CustomPhoneStateListener();
        // telephony.listen(customPhoneListener,
        // PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        // context = getApplicationContext();

        final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(ACTION_OUT);
        filter.addAction(ACTION_IN);
        this.br_call = new CallBr();
        this.registerReceiver(this.br_call, filter);

        // if(terminate != null) {
        // stopSelf();
        // }
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    public class CallBr extends BroadcastReceiver {
        Bundle bundle;
        String state;
        String inCall, outCall;
        public boolean wasRinging = false;

        @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_IN)) {
                if ((bundle = intent.getExtras()) != null) {
                    state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                    if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                        inCall = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                        wasRinging = true;
                        Toast.makeText(context, "IN : " + inCall, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) 
                    {
                        if (wasRinging == true)
                        {

                            Toast.makeText(context, "ANSWERED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            String out = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh-mm-ss").format(new Date());
                            File sampleDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/RenzymTest123");
                            if (!sampleDir.exists()) 
                            {
                                try
                                {
                                    sampleDir.mkdirs();
                                }
                                catch(Exception e)
                                {
                                    Log.d("make directory",e.toString());
                                }
                            }

                            out = out.replace(" ", "");
                            out = out.replace("-", "");

                            String file_name = "Recordaa";
                            try {
                                audiofile = File.createTempFile(file_name, ".amr", sampleDir);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

                            recorder = new MediaRecorder();
//                          recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);

                         //recorder.reset();

                           recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
                            recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.DEFAULT);
                            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
                            recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
                            try {
                                recorder.prepare();
                                recorder.start();

                            } 
                            catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) { 
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            recordstarted = true;
                        }
                    } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                        wasRinging = false;
                        Toast.makeText(context, "REJECT || DISCO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        if (recordstarted) {
                            recorder.stop();
                            recordstarted = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_OUT)) {
                if ((bundle = intent.getExtras()) != null) {
                    outCall = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "OUT : " + outCall, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }



}
```

When I use this 
`recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);`

I got exception while staring the recoder 
`Exception : java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed`

I have searched on previosly asked asked questions but didnt find any solution
on link [Android Media Recording: java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23465821/android-media-recording-java-lang-runtimeexception-start-failed)

it says to use 
`recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);` instead of voice call but records outing voice not incoming voice. How can I record incoming voice

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18887636/how-to-record-phone-calls-in-android

Comment: yes i got the code from there ... but did'nt find solution ... kindly help regarding recording of incoming call voice

Answer (score 0):

An audio source of MIC should record incoming calls. You can set recording volume to the maximum level and turn on loudspeaker too as follows:

//before recording
    AudioManager audioManager;

```
    //turn on speaker
     audioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
     audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
    //increase Volume
     audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL), 0);
```

//start recording

```
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
    recorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(320000);
    recorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
    File audioFile = File.createTempFile("temp", "3gp", path);
    recorder.setOutputFile(audioFile.getAbsolutePath());
    recorder.prepare();     
    recorder.start();
```

Also there are other constants you can use with setAudioSource(), Just follow the [guide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html) to understand how each works